# Identity's Register Method Not working on IIS

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, identity

I have Implemented ASP.NET Identity management and its working fine when i run my application on Local. Then i Deployed it to IIS , Now the 'Register' method of Account Controller in Identity is throwing me Unauthorized response.

I have updated my Connection string too. Even I hit the same URL from Postman , I am getting the result '200 OK'. That is the user is getting inserted in 'AspNetUsers' Table

Please Help What is the Problem.
Is Something Went wrong deploying the application. i have deployed it like 5 times freshly.

My Register Method :-

```
// POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, modelError.CreateModelError(ModelState));
        }
        try
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };

            IdentityResult result = UserManager.Create(user, model.UserName);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Identity_Insert", "Failed");
                httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            employeeMaster.LogError<EmployeeMaster>(ex, Global.Class.Common.ErrorType.APIError, 0);
            httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
        return httpResponseMessage;
    }
```

Comment: Do you get the unauthorized response when calling the `register` api? If yes, is this method decorated with `[authorize]` attribute?

Comment: nope @rad , its not decorated with [authorize] instead i used [AllowAnonymous]

Comment: Please provide the register api code.

Comment: @rad , Updated. Have a Look.